# deploy website using cpanel godaddy

Tags: java, spring, hosting, cpanel, web-hosting

I have created website in spring framework and now i want to host on cpanel godday. used Apache Tomcat v7 server through Java EE - Eclipse. I decided to go online and I bought a web hosting service from GoDaddy. I have access to the cPanel now and I know how to make one html page online by adding it to the *public_html* folder. My question is how can I deploy my website that I created and I have in a WAR file? Where should I upload the WAR file exactly? Is there anything I need to install first?

Answer (score 0):

GODaddy doesn't support Java Hosting.

https://in.godaddy.com/help/do-your-shared-hosting-accounts-support-java-1734

Comment: Is that confirmed that Godaddy dont support java hosting?

Answer (score -1):

You need to purchase **VPS hosting** to host your java app on Godaddy.
**Watch out [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1Arn59KIr0)**.

You can also host your java apps on [**AWS**](https://aws.amazon.com/) (Free for 12 months)